# Unable to repartition my data disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

Last week I started having problems with my Mac (a mid-2010 Mac Pro running OS X El Captain), after searching for the cause I realized my OS X partition was corrupt.

A while back I turned on FileVault, and 2-3 weeks later all of a sudden my Mac started slowing down. In the end, 5 minutes after booting up my Mac simply froze, I wasn't able to do anything any more.

I decided to reinstall OS X but to my horror I realized that I couldn't select my original disk any more. No matter what I tried (I even booted up using a Windows 10 install disk to remove all the partitions on the disk) , I couldn't get OS X to reinstall on the same disk.

I finally gave up, installed it on the 2nd disk, installed Paragon Hard Disk Manager which allowed me to finally create a new partition on the disk, and started using it as a data disk.

I thought I had solved the problem, until I wanted to turn on encryption on the disk. I got an error message, which Google told me meant I didn't have an EFI partition on the disk.

So I googled around for a solution, found one but it made everything worse. Now even Paragon Hard Disk Manager can't create a working partition any more.

So... How do I clean up this mess? I have a working OS X install, I just want to create another partition on my other disk and encrypt it...

How can I fix this?

Output `sudo gpt -r show disk1`:

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34        2014         
        2048  1953519616      1  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1953521664        3471         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

When I first executed `diskutil list` the list said there was a "Microsoft Basic Data" partition" on  the disk. Probably the partition Paragon app tried to create:

```
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE               IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data                         1.0 TB     disk1s1
```

I'm not certain the disk isn't failing, but my current problem started after me trying to recreate the EFI partition, so I'm assuming it's still a logical problem rather than an actual hardware problem.

Comment: How certain are you that the drive itself isn't failing?

Comment: Please start Terminal.app and enter `diskutil list`. Now search for the disk identifier of the stubborn internal disk (e.g. disk0). Enter `sudo gpt -r show diskX` (with diskX: the disk identifier of the internal disk) and add the result to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable FileVault on a non-system disk you need an EFI partition, an HFS+ volume and a Boot OS X partition. The last one will be built while enabling FileVault.

Your disk contains none of them.

Open Disk Utility (in /Applications/Utilities), choose the appropriate disk (not any inferior volume!) and hit erase in the toolbar.

Choose a name, "OS X Extended (Journaled)" as format and "GUID Partition Map" as scheme. Then hit the erase button.

If the partitioning fails, close Disk Utility and open Terminal.app. Enter `diskutil list`. Then enter `sudo gpt -r show diskX` with diskX: the disk identifier of the stubborn disk. Below I assume the identifier is *disk1*.

If you are sure that you have chosen the stubborn disk (I.e. the one with the *2048  1953519616      1  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7* partition) enter:

```
diskutil umountDisk disk1
sudo gpt destroy disk1
```

Enter `exit` to terminate the Terminal session and quit Terminal. Open Disk Utility again and repeat the steps to partition the disk mentioned earlier.

Comment: Since I already tried to recreate the partition using the Disk Utility I skipped this part and immediately went to the next step. After executing the commands and rebooting my system I finally maged to recreate my partitions :)

Comment: @Fysicus The hardware of your disk may still be corrupted though. I try to find an appropriate tool. I'm using a tool called [Scannerz](http://scsc-online.com/Scannerz.html),  which isn't free.

Comment: I'll run a scan then. I just hope I don't have to replace my disk. :(